# Как из JS скрипта вызвать C# код

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет! Я пишу ASP.NET приложение в котором нужно отобразить данные на круговой диаграмме. Для этого я использовал CanvasJS.Chart. Подскажите как теперь можно инициировать событие по нажатию на определенный участок диаграммы и вызвать C# код?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var males = @ViewBag.Male;
var females = @ViewBag.Female;
window.onload = function () {

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Пол"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "pie",
            startAngle: 240,
            indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
            dataPoints: [
                { y: males, label: "М" },
                { y: females, label: "Ж" },
            ]
        }]
    });
    chart.render();

}
```

Comment: Вызвать вы сможете только javascript функцию. Как создать событие внутри чарта [вот тут описано](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/event-handling/). Как вариант нарисуйте кнопку на asp и повесьте событие клика. А в чарте эмулируйте нажатие на кнопку. Данные можно в какие нибудь скрытые поля вставить или попробовать передать параметрами. в asp не силен

Comment: Спасибо! Выходит внутри чарта в принципе нельзя C# код вставить?

Comment: В браузере работает только javascript. Посмотрите еще вот эту страницу, может поможет [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949858/how-to-use-inline-c-sharp-in-the-browser-instead-of-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949858/how-to-use-inline-c-sharp-in-the-browser-instead-of-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать вызвать событие onclick в js, которое будет отправлять формой get/post запрос на нужный вам url. А там уже что-то делать с этими данными.

js:

```
function yourEvent(data) {
    var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
        '<input type="text" name="yourData" value="' + data + '"/>' +
        '</form>');
    $('body').append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

c#:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var = HttpContext.Current?.Request?.Form["yourData"].ToString();
}
```